# I need a way to find all instances of a string and then get everything from the end of that string to another string

Tags: python, string, substring

I need a way to find all instances of a string and then get everything from the end of that string to another string.

An example of what i want:

```
string = '''
<country:England> abcdafsasffasfafasasasffsafdafuiugiugigoog
af <country:Spain> asfasfigfasgyafsguiosfbsafbuiasfuis
faiufsabasfbuiasfbfas <country: Italy>asfasfhasfhgasfgasiafs'''
```

For all instances of the word country, i want to get the name of the country after

```
Output = [England, Spain, Italy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#re.findall) can do that for you. The below will capture all groups of word characters (`\w+`), in a pattern that starts with string "country:" followed by an optional space, and ending with ">"

```
import re

output=re.findall(r"country: ?(\w+)>",string)
```

`print(output)` results in:

```
['England', 'Spain', 'Italy']
```